# class not registered

Tags: vb.net

I am installing an application on a client machine.  The application is throwing an exception that I am logging that states "Class Not Registered".  This an app written in Visual Studio 2005 using VB.NET.  The dll dependencies of my .exe are located in the same folder as the .exe.  What class is this talking about and how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you share more details about the exception?

Comment: InnerException is blank.  I am returning ex.Message and logging it.  That is giving "Class not registered" nothing more

Comment: Which dll's does your project depend on? Do they in turn have any other dependencies?

Comment: They do and I placed all those in the folder as well.  The dll are Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll, Microsoft.SqlServer.Rmo.dll, Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.dll, Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll.

BatchParser is a dependency of one of those I placed that in there still no go.

Comment: It seems as if your application needs SQL Server around. Is any SQL Server edition installed on the client machine?

Comment: SQL Server is not installed on the client.  I am trying to initiate replication from the client machine by connecting to one instance of SQL Server and initiating a sync with another instance of SQL on a seperate machine.  Neither of the SQL Server installs are located on the client.

Comment: You will probably need some SQL Server edition installed; I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Does the application use any COM components? If so, make sure that they get registered properly on the client machine. You can either have the setup do this for you (if you have created a setup), or use the [regsvr32](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/regsvr32.mspx?mfr=true) utility.

Based on the comments, I would say that you will need to install SQL Server on the client machine. I am no SQL Server expert, but I would guess it would be sufficient with the Client Components.

Comment: This might also be due to a missing dependency on the target.

Comment: When I load the project into a setup project it shows four dependencies, each of which are .NET dlls.  Those four dlls are in the same folder as the .exe on the client machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out most/all of the code in the project (or create a hello,world setup) to isolate whether it's one of your 4 dependencies or something else entirely.